What are the grammatical rules for identifying parts of a sentence joined by conjunctions?
I met a sentence while reading a paper:

A key is represented in a partial-key tree by a pointer to the data
record containing the key value for the key, and a partial key.

Given that I do not understand the semantics of the sentence, I failed to identify what parts of the sentence are joined by conjunctions.
The question is how are
"a pointer to the data record containing the key value for the key"
and
"a partial key" identified as joined by the preposition by?
I thought that
"a partial-key tree by a pointer to the data record containing the key value for the key" and
"a partial key" are parts of the sentence joined by in.
I wonder where I am wrong?

"By" and "in" are not conjunctions. The only conjunction in your example is "and".

@BillJ yes and I am confused to find which parts are joined by the “and”

It's technical so I can't be sure. I suppose it could be the noun phrases "the key value for the key" and "a partial key".

This example is difficult because it's about a highly technical topic. What if we use the same syntax, but substitute less technical items:

A car is represented in a dealership's inventory by a number indicating its parking spot, and by a serial number.

(This sounds like a terrible system, but just making something up.)
It sounds like you're confused about the roles of in and of by in this sentence. It might help (though it's not required) if we set the "in" phrase off with commas:

A car is represented, in a dealership's inventory, by a number indicating its parking spot and by a serial number.

In other words, the car is represented by two numbers, the parking spot and the serial. And this representation happens within the context of the inventory. Applying this back to your original sentence, a key is represented by a pointer and by a partial key, and this happens in the context of a partial-key tree.
You could simplify this "in"/"by" syntax still further: "You are represented in Congress by senators and representatives." So you see, "in" only applies to "Congress," not all the rest of the remaining sentence.

I'm deeply suspicious of is represented by in the cited text - it seems to me what follows actually is what the partial key consists of. But putting that aside, I believe that even in a context where the primary key values themselves are "unique" (so any given primary key value uniquely identifies a single "row" of data), the "partial key" values are not necessarily unique. So a "pointer to the data record containing the key value" always uniquely identifies one specific row, but the partial key might not (it's only there to optimize certain queries)...

...which isn't the same as your "dealer's car" context. In that situation, either of the "keys" uniquely identifies the specific car.

@FumbleFingers Well, as long it's hypothetical, perhaps a truncated serial number then, like the first 4 digits.

Ah, right! Yeah, that would "map" nicely to what I understand OP's cited text to be getting at. Truth be told, I didn't know exactly what "partial key" meant here, until I asked Google Gemini whether each different partial key value was perforce unique in a database where the primary keys are definitely unique (answer - not necessarily).

Thank you! I see your example uses 2 ‘by’ and it is clear enough for me. But what if only 1 ‘by’ like this:” A car is represented, in a dealership's inventory, by a number indicating its parking spot, and a serial number.” ?Could I complete it as “ A car is represented, in a dealership's inventory, by a number indicating its parking spot, and (IN) a serial number.”?

@XavierZ. The short answer is “no,” but it’s not so much for grammatical reasons as for reasons of meaning. I’ll edit my answer when I have time to explain more. Also, I suspect the comma in the original quote is part of what makes it confusing for you. it isn’t grammatically needed and can be ignored.

A key is represented in a partial-key tree by// a pointer to the data record containing the key value for the key// and a partial key.
There are two parts to the sentence.
A key is represented in a partial-key tree by 1) a pointer to the data record containing the key value for the key AND [by] 2) a partial key.
So a key is represented by TWO THINGS.
Another example:
The people are represented in a democracy by 1) an elected body such as a parliament AND 2) its members.
Passive sentences have agents: maids and gardeners:
The mansion was cleaned BY maids and [by] gardeners.
Conjunctions like and and but can be used to join noun phrases, nouns, verbs, and prepositional phrases. [Hope I didn't forget any. :)]

Thank you! With context knowledge I can identify those two part correctly, but I wonder how with only grammar rules. In other word, what is wrong in term of grammar with following: The people are represented in 1) a democracy by an elected body such as a parliament AND 2) its members.

There is nothing wrong with it. Try doing it in Spanish or French and you will see. I put the numbers in the wrong place. It should be: are represented in a democracy 1) by an elected body such as parliament AND [by] its members. is represented BY A and B. A passive sentence.

Thank you and can I think that there are some intrinsical ambiguity within the usage of conjunctions like this?

I can't answer that in the abstract. [intrinsic, no al] Passive sentences are just passive sentences. The symphony that day was played by professional musicians and amateurs. Your sentence just has a very long first agent and a very short second one. It's possible perhaps to shorten it but I am not a CP nerd. Sorry. :)

Conjunctions (and coordination) are often ambiguous in their structure. Grammatically speaking, it could be the structure in @Lambie's answer (which I suspect is correct), or could be "a record containing 1) the key value for the key and 2) a partial key".
